# Chaning mutliple lambdas from Node12 to Node16, will there be any issues with this?

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, aws-sdk-nodejs

AWS will soon stop supporting Node 12 and prior versions as it's approaching end of life.

I have concerns if I upgrade from node 12 to node 16 if there's going to be any sytnax or semantic changes in the new version of node. I searched the internet and found one case where everything went successful; however, I am not certain.

I'm wondering if anyone knows if Node 12 vs Node 16 has any critical changes that could potentially break the code or not be backward compatible?

Comment: I think the syntax issue might be a minor problem compared to library supports and the associated dependency updates you might need. You could use nvm (https://npm.github.io/installation-setup-docs/installing/using-a-node-version-manager.html) to easily switch between node versions locally and test how easy the migration could be or not (yarn/npm install => yarn/npm run build and see how long the error stack is)

Comment: Without actual code, the best answer is that there may be issues for you. I'd test for any breaking changes in your development environment - By the way, according to what I've read, Node 12 LTS was end-of-life over 5 months ago and node 16 is about to move from "Active LTS" to "Maintenance" mode next month (like 4 days?)

Comment: This is what unit tests are for.  You can never "know for sure" just by reading release notes.  You have to test with new versions.  Just trying to update all your dependencies and run them in node 16 will give you some info.  Then running your unit tests in node 16 should give you more info.

Comment: Here's [an article](https://www.theimmigrantprogrammers.com/p/everything-about-the-latest-nodejs-283) that describes going from 12 to 16 and "says" there are no breaking changes (which is probably not really true).  That still doesn't mean that you can't have problems with some of your dependencies if they might be reaching into undocumented, "private" nodejs internals that could have changed behavior.  You will have to test to know for sure.

Comment: Description of a [breaking change](https://blog.logrocket.com/node-js-15-whats-new-and-how-the-developer-experience-has-improved/) in v16 - Unhandled rejections are now an error, not just a warning.